# Como almacenar información temporal de forma segura sin bases de datos

Tags: php, javascript

estoy haciendo una página donde almaceno información (puntos) que un usuario consigue dentro de la misma para que luego pueda acceder a un contenido si dispone de una cantidad mínima en ellos.

La información quiero que se guarde solo mientras el usuario esté en la ventana, es decir, lo mismo que hacen las variables de JavaScript, pero **quiero que sea más seguro, es decir, que no cualquiera pueda cambiarlos incluso con la consola del navegador**.

He pensado en PHP, pero no sé si tiene el mismo problema o no. ¿Alguna idea? No quiero usar Base de Datos para algo tan temporal y sencillo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque es una base de datos SQLite está embebida y es fácil de usar: [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) creo que cumple con lo que quieres. Por otra parte puedes usar el localstorage: [LocalStorage javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) Espero te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la variable de sesion de PHP puedes almacenarlo, así te aseguras que el usuario no podrá modificarlo.

```
$_SESSION['puntos'] = $_POST['puntos']; //Por ejemplo
```

Desde JavaScript el usuario siempre podrá cambiar los valores si quiere, la única manera de almacenarlo de forma segura (en el sentido de que el usuario no pueda modificarlo) es desde el servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Podés usar [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) de javascript.

> La propiedad `localStorage` te permite acceder al objeto local `Storage`.
>   localStorage es similar a `sessionStorage`. La única diferencia es que,
>   mientras los datos almacenados en localStorage no tienen fecha de
>   expiración, los datos almacenados en sessionStorage son eliminados
>   cuando finaliza la sesion de navegación - lo cual ocurre cuando se
>   cierra el navegador.
>
> Con `sessionStorage` los datos persisten sólo en la ventana/tab que los
>   creó, mientras que con `localStorage` los datos persisten entre
>   ventanas/tabs con el mismo origen.

Por ejemplo:

```
// seteo puntos
localStorage.setItem('puntos', 9999);

// accedo a la variable
console.log(localStorage.puntos);

// elimino la variable
localStorage.removeItem('puntos');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Una pregunta, ¿puedo usar entonces: localStorage.puntos++; para aumentarlos en uno?

Comment: Si, puedes hacerlo tranquilamente.

Comment: Vale, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Acaba de usar la consola y me permite cambiar sus valores, eso es la razón por la que no uso las variables de JavaScript.

Comment: Del lado del cliente nunca vas a poder evitar que se cambie una variable. En ese caso la única manera es del lado del servidor.

Comment: Vale, entonces ¿si lo hago con PHP no podrán cambiarlo?